# Combining styles for raster layer using QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, style

Is it possible to combine several styles of raster representation in QGIS as it is possible with vector layers?

My goal is to made a representation like the figure below, where a DTM is represented by a combination of shading and hypsometric tints.

[image: Raster visualisation example]

I have found a solution which is to duplicate the layer and assign the shading to the lower layer and the colours to the upper layer (with some transparency), but this is not very satisfactory.

Comment: Why is your current solution not satisfying?

Comment: Make two copies of your layer. Set a hillshade styling on your lower layer. Set a singleband pseudocolor on the upper, adjust min/max, green to red color ramp, blending mode "Multiply", ~30 % opacity, adjust brightness and saturation

Comment: @Erik I want to be able to generate a style file to apply to any DTM

Comment: You'd need to create two styles and apply each of them. Sure, it's kind of annoying if done every day, but perfectly doable.

Comment: The problem is not really that I am lazy, but that it is an operation that should be possible to do by many users with a very variable mastery of GIS. That's why I wanted to avoid using a method that required duplicating the raster layer.